# SQL Plus procedure error

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create the procedure which blurs some of the info if the condition is satisfied. I am able to create the procedure, but the execution doesn't work!

This is the table:

```
drop table orders;
create table Orders(
OrderID        number,
Firstname        varchar2(10),
State            varchar2(2),
ProductDescription    varchar2(20),
Qty            number,
ItemPrice        number);

insert into Orders values(1, 'Inaae', 'Kim','IL','hard drive', 2,200);
insert into Orders values(3, 'Lisa','Simpson','CA','Books',5,25);
insert into Orders values(4, 'Bart','Simpson','MD','Video',20,3);
insert into Orders values(5, 'Inaae','Kim','WA','ear ring',3,10);
insert into Orders values(6, 'Hommer','Simpson','IN','Beer',50,2);
insert into Orders values(7, 'Marge','Simpson','FL','coffee machine',1,150);
insert into Orders values(8, 'Gerret','W','NY','Chair',1,180);
```

This is the code for procedure:

```
create or replace function fn_extended_price(itemprice IN NUMBER, Qty IN NUMBER) RETURN        NUMBER
as
begin
          RETURN itemprice * Qty;
end;
/

create or replace procedure sp_order
as
cursor c_order is select OrderId, Firstname, Lastname, ProductDescription, Qty,    itemprice, State from Orders;


   order_val c_order %ROWTYPE;
   vOrder char(20); --will handle extention price blur
   vQty number;
   vItemPrice number;
   vState varchar2(2);
   begin

   FOR order_val in c_order LOOP
   vOrder := fn_extended_price(order_val.itemprice, order_val.Qty);
   vQty := order_val.Qty;
   vItemPrice := order_val.itemprice;
   vState := order_val.State;

   if vState = 'CA' OR vState = 'MD' OR vState = 'IL' THEN
      vOrder :='*********';
      vQty   :='********';
      vItemPrice :='******';
   end if;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Order ID: ' || order_val.orderid);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First Name: ' || order_val.firstname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last Name: ' || order_val.lastname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Description: ' || order_val.ProductDescription);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Qty: ' || order_val.Qty);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Price::' || order_val.itemprice);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Extended Price: $' || vOrder);
  END LOOP;      
 end;
 /
```

THE ERROR IS:

```
SQL> exec sp_orders
BEGIN sp_orders; END;

  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SP_ORDERS' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Can anyone tell me what is the mistake??

Thank you

Comment: What is the error you are getting so people can help you?

Answer (score 2):

You have named your procedure as `sp_order`, yet you are trying to run a procedure named `sp_orders`.

What is more, you are trying to store `******` value in a NUMBER variable in your code which will yield a `"PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"` exception, change your procedure as follows:

```
create or replace procedure sp_order
as
cursor c_order is select OrderId, Firstname, Lastname, ProductDescription, Qty,    itemprice, State from Orders;


   order_val c_order %ROWTYPE;
   vOrder char(20); --will handle extention price blur
   vQty number;
   vItemPrice number;
   vState varchar2(2);
   begin

   FOR order_val in c_order LOOP
   vOrder := fn_extended_price(order_val.itemprice, order_val.Qty);
   vQty := order_val.Qty;
   vItemPrice := order_val.itemprice;
   vState := order_val.State;

   if vState = 'CA' OR vState = 'MD' OR vState = 'IL' THEN
      vOrder :='*********';
      vQty   :=NULL;
      vItemPrice :=NULL;
   end if;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('---------------------------------');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Order ID: ' || order_val.orderid);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('First Name: ' || order_val.firstname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Last Name: ' || order_val.lastname);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product Description: ' || order_val.ProductDescription);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Qty: ' || order_val.Qty);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Price::' || order_val.itemprice);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Extended Price: $' || vOrder);
  END LOOP;      
 end;
 /
```

Comment: The `begin` part was SQL*Plus echoing back the command to highlight the error; it shows the expanded `begin`/`end` version of the `exec`. It just wasn't formatted properly in the question.

Comment: OK, I was executing it as exec sp_order, it was just a indentation problem and a typo during the question post. The problem was data type and thank you for fixing it. Now, I am able to execute the procedure but it does not return anything

Comment: You won't see any output from dbms_output.put_line unless you first do 'set serveroutput on'.